# Mouseenter not working for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a code where i need to trigger a functionality when mouse is over to specific  elements.

Its working fine for below code for all static

```
$("table td").on("mouseenter",function(){
    console.log("mouse entered")
});
```

but for all dynamic `<td class="editcolumn">XYZ</td>` event is not triggering even if i use below code

```
$("table td").on("mouseenter",".editcolumn",function(){
    console.log("mouse entered")
});
```

Any idea how to make it work. I'm using jQuery 1.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I just commented, but I figured I would show you an example:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tablee" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tablehead">
            <th>This</th>
            <th>is</th>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>table</th>
            <th>header</th>
            <th>and</th>
            <th>stuff</th>
            <th>though</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr class="append">
        <td class="edit-column">asdf</td>
        <td class="edit-column">qwer</td>
        <td class="edit-column">zxcv</td>
        <td class="edit-column">rtyu</td>
        <td class="edit-column">tyui</td>
        <td class="edit-column">dfgh</td>
        <td class="edit-column">dfgh</td>
        <td class="edit-column">wert</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ... -->
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" class="add-column" value="Add Column" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.add-column').click(function() {
        $('.append').append("<td class='edit-column'>iueo</td>");
        $('.tablehead').append("<th>Mo columns</th>");
    });
                                  /*  vvv - this   */
    $("#tablee").on('mouseenter', '.edit-column', function() {
    /* ^^^ should be children or a child of this */
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
});
```

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdebc8ma/2/)**


**[This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)** gives a much better explanation of delegated events.

Comment: Anytime. The reason your function didn't work is because the second parameter passed to the `on` method is meant to catch events of **children** of the original selector. `$('#tablee').on('mouseenter', '.edit-column', function() {});` would also do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced a similar problem for dynamic elements that are added or removed. In such situations you can create dynamic elements with event-handlers attached to their **attributes** i.e. in your case you can put the desired operations in a function which gets called by your attribute event handlers:

It should be something like this:

**Javascript:**

```
 function whenMouseEnters() {
    // perform some operations
 }
```

**Html:**

```
<td onmouseenter="whenMouseEnters()">
```

Answer (score 0):

If table is aviable on DOM load you can write delgated event for the **td** with class **editColumn**  like this:

```
$("table").on("mouseenter",".editcolumn",function(){
   console.log("mouse entered")
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried but its not working

Comment: table is also added dynamically?

Comment: Nope. Only columns are added.

Comment: `$(document).on("mouseenter", "td.editcolumn", function() {});` maybe?

Comment: Yes. Its working with $(document).on("mouseenter", "td.editcolumn", function() {});

Comment: can you post html as well in question and complete code wrapped in ``document.ready``

Comment: thanks guys for help. Its working if i put $(document) instead of $("table") for mouseenter even of dynamic content. Not sure why but it works

Comment: its because table is also coming dynamically, table was not rendered on DOM load